# matplotlib plotting very slow on one system but not another

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, matplotlib

I have two MacBook Pro laptops running more or less identical code, which plots N `pyplot` curves in a loop. One is fast, one is very slow. They are both using the `MacOSX` `matplotlib` backend. However, the fast one is running via PyCharm, and the slower one via CLI in iTerm. Might there be very different resources allotted to these two applications..? I'm at a loss. Numerous other `matplotlib` backends were tried on the slower machine, with no change.

Comment: You'd want to eliminate any machine-specific factors first. Have you tried running the same script from a terminal directly on both machines? Any difference? If no, there's a slew of possible causes - resources assigned, whether or not the script is run with debugging, etc. Why are you interested in the performance difference in completely different editing environments?

Comment: iTerm version might be running on built-in system python, and may not have correct privilege to cache any data. Rendering text (for matplotlib) is particularly slow without caching. PyCharm is almost guaranteed to have its own python distribution, and have permissions and libraries set up correctly. call `sys.executable` to see where the python executable you're currently running resides (from both iTerm, and PyCharm).